# Load Testing with Apache Bench for a long period of time

Tags: load-testing, apachebench

I want to do a load test on a server for 6 hours.

I'm using Apache Bench (ab) for testing, it seems there is no option for setting Test Duration in this tool, so I did set a big number for `-n` option which is the Number of Requests, but it doesn't matter what number you set for `-n`, it only sends 50000 requests!

Why?! How can I send more than 50000?

Example:

```
ab -n 35000000 -t 22000 -c 500 "URL"
```